# Mark letters that differ between two cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string-comparison

Given two cells, each containing a string of length n (i.e. 11), I want to mark all letters in the bottom cell in bold, red that differ from the cell at the top.

Here is a toy example:

[image]

Why is this useful? I need to compare many amino acid sequences with each other, and this would be a great way to visualize the results in Excel for biologists.

Comment: Are these values actual text strings? or are they the results of formulas?  If the latter, the process will remove the formulas and replace them with just the text strings.

Comment: They are actual text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following function compares two strings, assuming 'rngWord1' as the original string, and 'rngWord2' the one to change:

```
Sub comparetwostrings(rngWord1 As Excel.Range, rngWord2 As Excel.Range)
    Dim l As Long

    If rngWord1.Value <> rngWord2.Value Then

        For l = 1 To Len(rngWord1.Value)   

            If Mid(rngWord1.Value, l, 1) <> Mid(rngWord2.Value, l, 1) Then
                rngWord2.Characters(l, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                rngWord2.Characters(l, 1).Font.Bold = True    
            Else 
                rngWord2.Characters(l, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack   
            End If

        Next l

    End If
End Sub
```

To run the function, a Command button called `CompareAllStrings` can be created. Inside, a range is defined to loop over, and perform pairwise string comparisons. Both 'rng1' and 'Offset' should be adjusted based on the specific Excel layout:

```
Private Sub btnCompareAllStrings_Click()
    Dim rng1 As Range, e As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("B2:Z2")
    For Each e In rng1
        comparetwostrings e, e.Offset(1, 0)
        comparetwostrings e.Offset(2, 0), e.Offset(3, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where would the command 'comparetwostrings(range("i1"),range("i2"))' have to go for it to replace "i2" with the proper font?

Comment: You would call this when you wanted to compare, the first range is `compareto` and the second range is `tocompare` so in the example, I1 is the cell that holds what it should be and i2 is what you wish to compare against that.